# Validation on inputs in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with 5 keys and I want to assign 5 fixed values to them and I want each key have unique values without being repeated and each time user can change the value but I need a validation for repeated values can anyone help me with the syntax?

```
state = {
     val1:'a',
     val2:'b',
     val3:'c',
     val4:'d',
     val5:'e',
}
```

This code below is for 2 keys:

```
validation = () => {
        if ((val1 === 'a' && val2 === 'a') || (val1 === 'b' && val2 === 'b')) {
            return 'error'
        } else {
            return null
        }
}
```

I know this is completely wrong, but I need a syntax for 5 keys.

Comment: What exactly has to be returned by `validation()`?

Comment: If you need to check whether  some `enteredValue` already present , you may simply use `Object.values(state).some(v => v == enteredValue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***.some*** and check if any of the variable inside the state already had the value.

If it has, then trigger validation error.

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
  val1:'a',
  val2:'b',
  val3:'c',
  val4:'d',
  val5:'e',
}


validation = (value) => {
  Object.keys(state).forEach((key , index) => {
    if(state[key] === value){
      return error;
    }
  })
}
```

Here value passed to the validation function is the new value change requested by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to check each value with every other value and decide if there there a duplicate, you can use a JavaScript Set for this, this is a data structure that only accepts unique values, if an array is converted to a set, it will automatically get rid of any duplicates. Then you can just check if the length of your current array is same as the set size, if not, then there is a duplicate.

```js
let state = {
     val1:'a',
     val2:'b',
     val3:'c',
     val4:'d',
     val5:'e',
}


function validateUnique(state) {

 const arrayOfValues = Object.values(state);
 const initalCount = arrayOfValues.length;
 return initalCount === (new Set(arrayOfValues)).size

}
```

Needless to say there are a lot more ways to do this, including a simple loop.